# How to use Kaggle datasets in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, kaggle

Is it possible to query Kaggle data directly from BigQuery, cloud to cloud?

Downloading from Kaggle and creating a table in BigQuery is one way, as recorded in [this](https://github.com/isis-santos-costa/kaggle-datasets-in-bigquery) GitHub repository.

Is there a way to run a query in BigQuery

- using a possibly existing Kaggle public project in BigQuery, and thus
  ↳ selecting `` FROM `kaggle-datasets-project.dataset.table` ``?
- or, alternatively, connecting to the Kaggle dataset in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to query a public kaggle dataset directly in the BigQuery UI console. You'll have to download the dataset and store it as a native dataset to be able to query it directly.

Alternatively, Kaggle data can be stored in external sources like [Drive](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-drive-data) or Google Cloud [Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-cloud-storage-data) and can be queried directly on the BQ console.

So to summarize,
You can query a BQ dataset on [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/48573), however public kaggle datasets cannot be queried directly on BQ console.